# Phonegap will not delete data from mongodb (mongolab)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js

I have built a small phonegap app in backbone.js which connects to a mongodb backend(hosted on mongolab) I can successfully retrieve and add to collections using the following url in my Backbone.Collection:

```
url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/site_manager/collections/items?apiKey=****************'
```

but when I try to delete a model from the collection it does not remove it from the db. I have set the urlRoot of my model with an /:id attribute:

```
urlRoot : 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/site_manager/collections/items/:id?apiKey=**********************'
```

but it still doesn't seem to be working - I'm not sure if i've put the id attribute in the right place. Everything works locally with a local server/db so I'm sure it has to do with the URL. Can anyone help with this please?

I am aware of security risks of accessing my db directly from the clientside with the API key but htis is just for a quick prototype.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/Proxy) or 
other tool that will allow you to monitor the HTTP requests and the returned status code that your application makes? At least you will be able to define where is problem.

Comment: I am getting a resonse of 400, it's an 'Access Control Allow Origin' error but I don't think that makes sense because I can 'add' and 'get' from the db. I'm sure the UrlRoot is incorrect... so the API key doesn't work

Comment: Okay, I have changed my urlRoot to url and tried using a hardcoded id which works : 
url:'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/site_manager/collections/items/559416de89d1b01045000002?apiKey=*****' - 

However when i try to replace it with +this.id+ it comes back as undefined - How do I pass the id to the model when calling this.model.destroy();